# Test dependency for two arbitrary random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I want to know if there is a way to calculate test the dependency of two random variables $X, Y$ no matter what their distributions are.

I know that if the probability distribution is known, we can check the value of $W=P(X, Y)-P(X)P(Y)$ and if it is equal to zero then we conclude they're independent.

What if we don't know the distribution? Is there any general way to learn the probability distribution?

Answer (score 1):

There are several *"non parametric tests"* to verify dependence between rv's

Just as an example

- $\chi^2$ test
- Spearman's $\rho$
- Kendall's $\tau$